# Android studio select search results

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio, search

I have simple problem with my Android app in Android Studio. I was to create two classes to add search `activity` in my app and was so successful. But, I have problem. The problem is that the user wants to select the person from the results and pass the user ID to another `activity` "**User_Profile**". But, I can't do this. Can anyone help me?

Search Class:

```
public class Search extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText se_input;
    RecyclerView results_list;
    DatabaseReference mUDB;
    FirebaseUser mFBU;
    SearchAdapter searchAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> fullNameList,userNameList, userIdList,profileImageList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        mUDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mFBU = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        se_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.se_input);
        results_list = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.results_list);
        results_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        results_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        results_list.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));


        /*
         * Create a array list for each node you want to use
         */
        fullNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        userNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        userIdList = new ArrayList<>();
        profileImageList = new ArrayList<>();

        se_input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    setAdapter(s.toString());

                } else {
                    /*
                     * Clear the list when editText is empty
                     */
                    fullNameList.clear();
                    userNameList.clear();
                    userIdList.clear();
                    profileImageList.clear();
                    results_list.removeAllViews();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void setAdapter(final String searchedString) {
        mUDB.child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                /*
                 * Clear the list for every new search
                 */
                fullNameList.clear();
                userNameList.clear();
                userIdList.clear();
                profileImageList.clear();
                results_list.removeAllViews();

                int counter = 0;

                /*
                 * Search all users for matching searched string
                 */
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String uid = snapshot.getKey();
                    String full_name = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    String user_name = snapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
                    String profile_pic = snapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);

                    if (full_name.toLowerCase().contains(searchedString.toLowerCase())) {
                        fullNameList.add(full_name);
                        userNameList.add(user_name);
                        userIdList.add(uid);
                        profileImageList.add(profile_pic);
                        counter++;
                    } else if (user_name.toLowerCase().contains(searchedString.toLowerCase())) {
                        fullNameList.add(full_name);
                        userNameList.add(user_name);
                        userIdList.add(uid);
                        profileImageList.add(profile_pic);
                        counter++;
                    }

                    /*
                     * Get maximum of 15 searched results only
                     */
                    if (counter == 15)
                        break;
                }

                searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(Search.this, fullNameList, userNameList, userIdList, profileImageList);
                results_list.setAdapter(searchAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

SearchAdapter Class:

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> fullNameList,userNameList, userIdList,profileImageList;


    class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        ImageView profileImage;
        TextView full_name, user_name,user_id;

        public SearchViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            profileImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
            full_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.full_name);
            user_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            user_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_id);
        }
    }


    public SearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> fullNameList, ArrayList<String> userNameList, ArrayList<String> userIdList, ArrayList<String> profileImageList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.fullNameList = fullNameList;
        this.userNameList = userNameList;
        this.userIdList = userIdList;
        this.profileImageList = profileImageList;
    }

    @Override
    public SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.search_list_item, parent, false);
        return new SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.full_name.setText(fullNameList.get(position));
        holder.user_name.setText(userNameList.get(position));
        holder.user_id.setText(userIdList.get(position));
        Glide.with(context).load(profileImageList.get(position)).into(holder.profileImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fullNameList.size();
    }
}
```

User Profile Class:

```
public class UserProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CircleImageView u_pro_img;
    private TextView u_user_name, u_fullname, u_bio, u_fricou;
    private Button add_fri;
    private DatabaseReference mUDBR;
    private TextView user_id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
        u_pro_img = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.u_pro_img);
        u_user_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.u_user_name);
        u_fullname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.u_fullname);
        u_bio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.u_bio);
        u_fricou = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.u_fricou);
        add_fri = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_fri);
        mUDBR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        user_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_id);
    }
}
```

I just want to pass the `user id` key to user **profile activity** when the user selects the person from the results. I hope you understand me.

Comment: I answered your question check & reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to send `userId` to **ProfileActivity**(Here sending data from **SearchAdapter** class )

```
      @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.full_name.setText(fullNameList.get(position));
        holder.user_name.setText(userNameList.get(position));
        holder.user_id.setText(userIdList.get(position));
      Glide.with(context).load(profileImageList.get(position)).into(holder.profileImage);



 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            //for sending data UserProfile 
            Intent intent  = new Intent(context,UserProfile.class);
            intent.putExtra("USER_ID",String.valueOf(userIdList.get(position)));
            context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }
```

on your **UserProfile.cass** get `userId` by following way :

```
String userId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
    u_pro_img = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.u_pro_img);
    u_user_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.u_user_name);
    u_fullname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.u_fullname);
    u_bio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.u_bio);
    u_fricou = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.u_fricou);
    add_fri = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_fri);
    mUDBR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    user_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_id);


     //Getting data here UserId
      userId = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_ID","");
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"USER ID "+userId ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  

}}
```

Comment: Thank you for help me,The code work 100% with me, again thank you very much.